# Lemma KL-Divergence (Differential Privacy)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler, differential-privacy, divergence

I am studying differential privacy and I got stuck again in proof of a lemma. Which is:

"$D_{\infty}^\delta(Y||Z) \leq \epsilon$ if and only if there exists a random variable $Y'$ such that $\Delta(Y,Y') \leq \delta$ and $D_\infty(Y||Z) \leq \epsilon $."

I have a problem understanding the reverse proof.

**Definitions:**

Be $Y, Z$ two random variables.

1. $\Delta (Y,Z) \overset{def}{=} \underset{S}{max} \ \ \ | Pr[Y\in S]-Pr[Z\in S]|$
2. $D_{\infty}(Y||Z)=\underset{S\subseteq Supp(Y)}{max}\Big[ln\frac{Pr[Y\in S]}{Pr[Z \in S]}\Big]$, which is the KL-Divergence between two distributions $Y,Z$
3. $D_{\infty}^\delta(Y||Z)=\underset{S\subseteq Supp(Y):Pr[Y\in S]\geq \delta}{max}\Big[ln\frac{Pr[Y\in S]-\delta}{Pr[Z \in S]}\Big]$

**Proof:**

Suppose that $D_{\infty}^\delta(Y||Z) \leq \epsilon$. Sea $S=\{y:Pr[Y=y] > e^\epsilon \cdot Pr[Z=y]\}$. Then

\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{y \in S}(Pr[Y=y]-e^\epsilon \cdot Pr[Z=y]) = Pr[Y \in S]-e^\epsilon \cdot Pr[Z \in S] \leq \delta
\end{equation*}

(I understand until here)

Moreover, if we let $T=\{y:Pr[Y=y] \leq Pr[Z=y]\}$, then :

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    \sum_{y\in T}(Pr[Z=y]-Pr[Y=y]) &= \sum _{y \notin T}(Pr[Y=y]-Pr[Z=Y]) \ \ \ (I-got-stuck-here) \\
    & \geq \sum _{y \in S}(Pr[Y=y]-Pr[Z=Y])\\
    & \geq \sum _{y \in S}(Pr[Y=y] > e^\epsilon \cdot Pr[Z=y])
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

(I don't' understand why:   $\sum_{y\in T}(Pr[Z=y]-Pr[Y=y]) = \sum _{y \notin T}(Pr[Y=y]-Pr[Z=Y]$)

Thus we can obtain $Y'$ from $Y$ by lowering the probabilities on $S$ and raising the probabilities on $T$ To satisfy:

1. For all  $y\in S$, $Pr[Y'=y]=e^\epsilon \cdot Pr[Z=y] < Pr[Y=y]]$
2. For all $y \in T$, $Pr[Y=y]\leq Pr[Y'=y]\leq Pr[Z=y]$
3. For all $y\notin S \cup T$, $Pr[Y'=y]=Pr[Y=y] \leq e^{\epsilon} \cdot Pr[Z=y]$

Then $D_{\infty}^\delta(Y'||Z) \leq \epsilon$ by inspection

**Reference:**
Dwork, C. & Roth, A. (2014). The Algorithmic Foundations of Differential Privacy. Foundations and Trends in Theoretical Computer Science, page 45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *any* set $T$, the reason
$$\sum_{y\in T}(Pr[Z=y]-Pr[Y=y]) = \sum _{y \notin T}(Pr[Y=y]-Pr[Z=y])$$
is that both $\Pr[Z=y]$ and $\Pr(Y=y)$ add to 1 over the entire sample, so $Pr[Y=y]-Pr[Z=y]$ adds to zero over the entire sample.

So
$$\sum_{y\in T}(Pr[Z=y]-Pr[Y=y]) + \sum _{y \notin T}(Pr[Z=y]-Pr[Y=y])=0$$
giving
$$\sum_{y\in T}(Pr[Z=y]-Pr[Y=y]) - \sum _{y \notin T}(Pr[Y=y]-Pr[Z=y])=0$$
and
$$\sum_{y\in T}(Pr[Z=y]-Pr[Y=y]) = \sum _{y \notin T}(Pr[Y=y]-Pr[Z=y])$$

Incidentally, $D_\infty(Y||Z)$ as you have defined it is **not** the KL-divergence. The KL-divergence is the expected value of the log likelihood ratio, not the supremum.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, Thomas. It makes sense. Yeah, that is not the KL divergence, but is similar (The Expression).